# Self-Adjointness for Banach Spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, operator-theory

Good evening. Is there a reasonable notion of being self-adjoint for the adjoint operator on Banach Spaces? Kind regards, Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among the first hits in Google are

> [The theory of self-adjoint operators in banach spaces with a Hermitian form](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01875301), V. A. Shtraus,
>   Siberian Mathematical Journal, 1978, Volume 19, Issue 3, pp 483-489

and

> [Self-adjoint operators on real Banach spaces](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0362546X13000035), Paweł Wójcik, Nonlinear Analysis: Theory, Methods & Applications, 2013,
>   Volume 81, pp 54–61.

The former uses continuous and Hermitian bilinear forms $Q:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ and calls an operator $A$ on $X$ $Q$-self-adjoint if $Q(Ax,y) = Q(x,Ay)$.

In a similar spirit I could imagine that the following construction could make sense:If you have a uniformly smooth Banach space $X$ you could use the duality mapping $J:X\to X^*$ defined by $J(x) = \{x^*\in X^*\ :\ \langle x^*,x\rangle_{X^*\times X}=\|x\|^2=\|x^*\|^2\}$ (which is single valued and uniformly continuous in this case) to define $Q(x,y) = \langle J(x),y\rangle_{X^*\times X}$ (however, not bilinear). Then it seems natural to require that $Q(Ax,y) = Q(x,Ay)$ (however, I haven't seen this construction used anywhere).

Comment: Hmm but they're both relying on introducing addition structure. My hope was that the purpose of the adjoint of an operator in hilbert spaces could be the same as for the adjoint of an operator in banach spaces so there could be a "universal" notion of self adjointness ...unfortunately i don't have acces to the latter hit from google

Comment: At least the approach with the duality mapping specializes to the Hilbert space case…

Comment: The book is "Spectral theory of linear operators" by H. R. Dowson.  You will find more references there.

Answer (score 3):

There are ways to define hermitian operators in complex Banach spaces without the latter having additional structure and these were studied in some detail in the 70's.  One way is to demand that the numerical range be real, another that the semi-group of operators generated by $iT$ consist of isometries.  A chapter of Dowson's book on spectral operators is devoted to them and this is probably the best entrance point
to  this topic and its relevance in spectral theory.

Comment: Oh can you give me more details where to read about these studies from the 70's ...I'm not so used to find things like this sry for that =/

Comment: The book is "Spectral theory of linear operators" by H.R. Dowson.  You will find more references there.